# Web deployment times out in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying an azure web deployment for the first time and its throwing me the error below,

(The website has been created on azure and accessible through browser - Web deploy tool seems to time out and having trouble connecting to azure.)

**Error 3   Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://waws-prod-am2-009.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=mysitename'.)
Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://waws-prod-am2-009.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=mysitename'.
The operation has timed out     0   0   mysitename
Appreciate any help on this.**

Comment: Having the same problem.  I'll let you know if I come up with a solution

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? It could be the ports blocked and web deploy times out. If so lias with the infrastructure team to get the required ports opened. They'll be able to open the ports for you.